# Как вывести определенное количество тегов таксономии?

Tags: wordpress

```
$cities = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'      => array( 'geo_countries'), // название таксономии с WP 4.5
            'orderby'       => 'name', 
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'    => true, 
            'object_ids'    => null,
            'include'       => array(),
            'exclude'       => array(), 
            'exclude_tree'  => array(), 
            'number'        => 2, 
            'fields'        => 'all', 
            'count'         => false,
            'slug'          => '', 
            'parent'         => $term,
            'hierarchical'  => true, 
            'child_of'      =>  '', 
            'get'           => 'all', // ставим all чтобы получить все термины
            'name__like'    => '',
            'pad_counts'    => false, 
            'offset'        => '', 
            'search'        => '', 
            'cache_domain'  => 'core',
            'name'          => '',    // str/arr поле name для получения термина по нему. C 4.2.
            'childless'     => false, // true не получит (пропустит) термины у которых есть дочерние термины. C 4.2.
            'update_term_meta_cache' => true, // подгружать метаданные в кэш
            'meta_query'    => '',
        ) );

foreach ($cities as $city) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="d-city" id="<?php echo $city->slug ?>" data-value="<?php echo $city->term_id?>">
        <label for="<?php echo $city->slug ?>"><?php echo $city->name ?></label>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/checked.svg" alt="#">
    </li>
    <?php 
}
```

В документации написано использовать свойство number.
Но все равно выводит все теги

Comment: Оставьте только нужные параметры и все заработает. number => 2 работает 100%)

Comment: Может нужно обернуть в кавычки? 'number'        => '2',